# JavaScript variable not defined error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

We have three JS files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pm.init.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pm.util.func.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pm.nav.js"></script>
```

In init.js we have:

```
$(function(){
    var dirty = false;
})
```

In util.func.js we have:

```
function dirtyCheck(actionFunction) {
    if (dirty == false) {
        actionFunction();
        return;
    }
    ...
```

And in nav.js we have:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn-nav-refresh').click(function() {
        dirtyCheck(function() { doRefresh(); });
    });
    ...
```

Now when the `btn-nav-refresh` function fires after a user clicks the button we get a `dirty is not defined` error.  Why is this??

Comment: Just remove the `var` before `dirty = false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel dirty myself telling you how to make your "dirty" variable into a dirty global variable, but it'd be like this:

```
$(function(){
  window.dirty = false;
})
```

You should however find a better way to do this. Here's an idea:

```
$(function() {
  $('body').data('dirty', false);
});
```

Then:

```
// ...
if (${'body').data('dirty')) takeBath();
```

Answer (score 2):

In init.js can't you just put `var dirty = false;` as a global variable and not inside a function definition?

Answer (score 2):

The variable dirty is only known in your closure. That's why.

```
$(function(){
    var dirty = false;
});
alert(dirty); // Undefined (same file, just one line after.
```

It's the main feature of the closure...

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, `dirty` is out of scope because it is enclosed by your document ready function.  Change your declaration to be like this instead:

```
var dirty = false;
$(function(){

});
```